# Alternative for GetElementsByTagName for filling a xmlnodelist

Tags: excel, getelementsbytagname, xmlnodelist, vba

I am looking for an alternative for filling a xmlnodelist.

Because the function GetElementsByTagName is only working with one “search condition”.  
I would like to add to this nodelist the tags “A” and  tags B both in one nodelist.
The code below is not correct because its only working for one tagname.
Anyone any idea? Maybe with a loop function?

`Src = filename
xmldoc.async = False
xmldoc.Load (src)
Set oNodeList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("A")`

Comment: Also asked at VBAExpress http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?54589-Alternative-for-GetElementsByTagName-for-filling-a-xmlnodelist

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `SelectNodes()` function  and XPath operators to submit an `Or` query (http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_operators.asp). Something like:

```
Set oNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//A | //B")
```